# Can't login to Dashboard when changing site URL to HTTPS

Tags: wp-admin, login, https, http

By mistake in my WordPress settings, I changed `http` to `https`, and saved it.

After it, an option come that "You have to login again", but when I tried to access my website it gives error of SSL etc, now I want to get access, how is it possible to change `https` to `http` without WordPress login?

I have access to cPanel & domain.

Comment: Can you provide the image of this option in WordPress settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to your cpanel and go to php my admin, then find your db and there table wp_options, inside you will see URL of your website,2 fields. Change it how you like.

Comment: Good directions but would be good to be a bit more clear on which option keys to look for